# What does it mean for something to be "inter-ethnic?"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Does inter-ethnic refer to things that are between different ethnic groups, or within one ethnic group?

If it refers to things that are between different ethnic groups, what word would be used to refer to things that are within one ethnic group?

Answer (score 5):

*Inter* means *between*. The Latin prefix for *within* is *intra*. However I wouldn't use "intra-ethnic" -- in fact I can't think of a sentence which would refer to "things within one ethnic group". One might talk perhaps of "inter-ethnic conflict", but "intra-ethnic conflict"? I think not: it would be "ethnic Europeans (for example) are fighting amongst themselves".

Comment: The words *interethnic* and *intraethnic* are both used commonly enough to make [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interethnic%2C+inter+ethnic%2C+intra+ethnic%2C+intraethnic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), although they don't make my browser's spell-checker.

Comment: @Peter Shor: My (Google Chrome) spell-checker is perfectly happy with both so long as they're hyphenated. Which suits me because I think they *should* be. I know it's not a very smart spell-checker (it's also happy with *intra-invalid-words-in-this-construction*) but I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 1):

Google Books has 28,000 hits for [intra-ethnic](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20very%20chain%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_nf=1&ds=bo&pq=%22intraethnic%22&cp=7&gs_id=3l&xhr=t&q=%22intra-ethnic%22&pf=p&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22intra-ethnic%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=13e2384ef21332d9&biw=1264&bih=859) plus 15,000 for [intraethnic](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a%20very%20chain%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22intraethnic%22&oq=%22intraethnic%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=36320l36320l5l36606l1l0l1l0l0l0l0l0ll1l0&gs_l=serp.3...36320l36320l5l36606l1l0l1l0l0l0l0l0ll1l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=13e2384ef21332d9&biw=1264&bih=859), so it's not particularly unusual. Given *intra-* is a [common, productive prefix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intra-) signifying *inside, within, interior, during*, I disagree with Andrew's advice here to avoid the term completely. Though like the majority of those writers, I would avoid the unhyphenated version because it's a little tricky to read correctly at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

*[Intra](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intra-)-ethnic* conflict is a kind of conflict between or among people within the same ethnic group:

> prefix
>
> (Added to adjectives) on the inside; within:
>   *ODO*